# Compute the poles of $Y+X-1$ on the curve $Y^2=X^3+2X^2-3X$

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-space, rational-functions

Let the elliptic curve $E: Y^2 = X^3+2X^2-3X$ and the function $g: Y+X-1$.

I found that the zeros of $g$ on the curve $E$ (in projective coordinates) are
$S(1:0:1)$ with order $o_S = 2$ and $P(-1:2:1)$ with order $o_P = 1$.

How about the poles? There exists any pole of $g$ on the curve $E$ ?

**My thinking:** $g \rightarrow \infty$ when $X \rightarrow \infty$ or $Y \rightarrow \infty$ or both. But when we take a look on the curve equation $E$:

- if $X \rightarrow \infty$ then $X^3 \rightarrow \infty$ and it means $Y^2 \rightarrow \infty$ with the "same speed" as $X^3$ (because the equation holds). So in fact both $X$ and $Y$ must tend to infinity to have a pole. But what is exactly would be that pole or maybe it does not exist.

**Edit:**

Maybe I am wrong, but I would say that the only pole is the point at infinity $O(0:1:0)$ because $g = \frac{Y+X-Z}{Z}$ in projective coordinates. So $g \rightarrow \infty$ when $Z = 0$, which means that the only pole is $O$. Am I right ?

Comment: Correct, $\mathcal{O}$ is the only pole. If neither $X$ nor $Y$ has a pole at a point $P$, then $X+Y-1$ won't have a pole at $P$ either.

Comment: Is this a general fact @JyrkiLahtonen?. I mean for any variables $X_1,...,X_n$ which neither one does not have a pole at point $P$, any function in those variable also does not have a pole at point $P$ ? Or maybe it suffices that at least one $X_i$ to have a pole at $P$, so that the function in those variables has a pole at $P$... ?

Comment: No **polynomial** in those variables will have a pole. If we have denominators, then the scene may change.